# The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, certificate-authority, crl

I need to pass IIS certificate authentication on Windows Server 2012. The root cert haven't got any revocation lists but I'm getting exception:

> The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the
>   certificate

After searching, I found solution to disable revocation check by using CertUtil command:

```
certutil –setreg ca\CRLFlags +CRLF_REVCHECK_IGNORE_OFFLINE
```

and getting

> CertUtil: -setreg command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2)
>   CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify what certificate you're talking about ? Client ? Server ? Where does the error occure ?

Comment: I have the same error.